# MySQL to PHP Array

Tags: php, mysql

Can you please help me extracting MySQL data in php array.

my sql:

```
SELECT count(*) as total, post_type as type FROM wp_posts group by post_type;
```

to php, like below:

```
<?php $total = array(5,7, .. , ..); $type = array('Page', 'Post', '..',..'); ?>
```

Array should come from database

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you tried something?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get two separate arrays from single SQL query either you have to run the mysql query two times or Write a PHP code which gives you the desired result.

Your current query will give result as follow.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [total] => 5
        [post_type] => Page
    )
)
```

Now you have to traverse these array to create two separate arrays you want.

```
$total=array_column($result,'total');
$type = array_column($result,'post_type');
```

Above code will give you two separate arrays.

Thanks to [Niet the Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol) for [array_column](http://php.net/array-column), it looks more clean then traversing manually.

Comment: Alternative: `$total = array_column($result,'total'); $type = array_column($result,'post_type');` - [documentation](http://php.net/array-column)